How can I get the day of the week using std::chrono after having calculated the day/month/year?
I've calculated the day, day of month and year, and seconds, minutes, and hours using std::chrono::local_days, I just now need to get the day of the week. The code I'm using was given by Howard Hinnant on an answer here, comments are mine:
auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
static auto const tz = std::chrono::current_zone();
static auto info = tz->get_info(tp); // CACHE THE TIMEZONE INFO
if (tp >= info.end) // APPARENTLY THE TIME ZONE INFO CAN CHANGE UP TO TWICE A YEAR
    info = tz->get_info(tp);
auto tpl = std::chrono::local_days{} + (tp + info.offset - std::chrono::sys_days{});
auto tpd = floor<std::chrono::days>(tpl);
std::chrono::year_month_day ymd{ tpd };
std::chrono::hh_mm_ss hms{ tpl - tpd };

At this point I have the what I mentioned above, how can I get the day of the week with as few redundant calls as possible?

The other answers get the correct answer, but here is the most efficient method:
std::chrono::weekday wd{tpd};

Just convert your local_days to weekday.  This will get you the local weekday (because you converted from local_days).
All this conversion does is execute this low-level algorithm:
return static_cast<unsigned>(tpd >= -4 ? (tpd +4) % 7 : (tpd +5) % 7 + 6);

so it is about as efficient as you can get.

Other comments:

// APPARENTLY THE TIME ZONE INFO CAN CHANGE UP TO TWICE A YEAR

Actually more.  There is no limit to the craziness of politicians.
Here is a simpler way to get the local time (tpl):
auto tpl = tz->to_local(tp);

I don't recommend going thru the sys_info unless you are doing thousands of such conversions and need the very ultimate in performance.  Certainly for just starting out, just let the time_zone do the conversion for you.

You can convert the days to year_month_weekday, and then retrieve the weekday part.
std::chrono::year_month_weekday ymwd{ tpd };
std::chrono::weekday wd = ymwd.weekday();

To get an index from wd, you can call wd.c_encoding() or wd.iso_encoding(), depending on whether you want Sunday to be represented as 0 or 7.

So year_month_day and year_month_weekday need to be called separately?

@Zebrafish You can convert year_month_day to year_month_weekday as well: std::chrono::year_month_weekday ymwd{ ymd };.

Which constructor is that? I don't see any such constructor for the year_month_weekday type, I mean a constructor that takes a year_month_day https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_weekday/year_month_weekday

The explicit year_month_day to year_month_weekday conversion works by implicitly converting from year_month_day to sys_days, and then from sys_days to year_month_weekday.  Indeed, it is this very mechanism that allows any two calendrical systems (whether chromo-supplied or user-written) to explicitly convert to one another as long as both calendrical systems supply implicit conversions to and from sys_days.

You can get the weekday using the struct std::tm:
const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
const auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
std::stringstream output_stream;
struct tm time_info;
localtime_s(&time_info, &in_time_t);
std::cout << time_info.tm_wday << std::endl;

I would consider just replacing the code you have in your question with this, as the struct tm can be used to easily get the day of the year
time_info.tm_yday

Or daytime
time_info.tm_sec
time_info.tm_min
time_info.tm_hour


no just avoid these and use the modern std::chrono
